# MS Power Query usage of Index +/- 1 costly too much Time & Memory

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to change the format of my excel table with power query, for a easy usage on Power BI, but my query takes too much time and space (GygaBytes for a file of 70KB...) which is unaccetable, and I cannot figure it the reason and how can I fix it.

I have an excel file which records needs for execute programs/projects.
First two columns are 'Program' and 'Skill', while next columns are the months:
so each rows shows how many "person" are necessary of that skill for that program on that month;
excel file looks like this:
[image]

My Goal is to obtain from this format a table whith following columns: Program, Skill, Label, Start, Stop.

Where 'Start' and 'Stop' are the dates of the begininng and the end of the usage of that specific resource, and 'Label' is used to split same program-skill resources in different rows. For example from starting table, first two skill (Skill_A and Skill_B) of Program_1 will be:

[image]

I did it with 3 queries, first one just is usefull for opening the excel file,
secondone just, clean all programs needs in a different format,
last one is the query which I request support (named **Gantt**) where probably the usage of `[Index]-1` and `[Index]+1` generates this unwanted behaviour.

**File_pointer**

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Forecast_Resources.xlsx"), null, true),
    Foglio1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Foglio1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Foglio1_Sheet,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31", "Column32", "Column33", "Column34", "Column35", "Column36", "Column37", "Column38", "Column39", "Column40", "Column41", "Column42", "Column43", "Column44", "Column45", "Column46", "Column47", "Column48", "Column49", "Column50", "Column51", "Column52", "Column53", "Column54", "Column55", "Column56", "Column57", "Column58", "Column59", "Column60", "Column61", "Column62", "Column63", "Column64", "Column65", "Column66", "Column67", "Column68", "Column69"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Other Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

**Programs**

```
let
    Source = File_pointer,
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Usage"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Program", "Skill"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Program", type text}, {"Skill", type text}, {"Attribute", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year(Date.From([Attribute])), Int64.Type)
in
    #"Inserted Year"
```

**Gantt**

```
let
    Source = Programs,
    addColumnList = List.Accumulate({1..13}, Source, (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, "v" & Number.ToText(current), each [Value] - current)),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(addColumnList, {"Program", "Skill", "Attribute", "Value", "Year"}, "Attribute.1", "Value.1"),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Columns", each ([Value.1] >= 0)),
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sorted Rows1","v","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute.1"}),    
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[Program], "_", [Attribute.1]}), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Attribute.1", "Value.1"}),
    #"Inserted Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From([Attribute])), type date),
    #"Inserted End of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Month", "End of Month", each Date.EndOfMonth(Date.From([Attribute])), type date),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Inserted End of Month",{{"Program", Order.Ascending}, {"Skill", Order.Ascending}, {"Merged", Order.Ascending}, {"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Attribute", "Value", "Year"}),
    
    Label = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Label", each Text.Combine({[Skill], "__", [Merged]}), type text),
    #"EOM_plus" = Table.AddColumn(Label, "EOM_plus", each Date.AddDays([End of Month],1) , type date),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"EOM_plus", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"BEGINNING" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Beginning", each [Start of Month]<>#"Added Index"[EOM_plus]{[Index]-1} or [Label]<>#"Added Index"[Label]{[Index]-1}, type logical),
    #"ENDING" = Table.AddColumn(#"BEGINNING", "Ending", each [EOM_plus]<>#"Added Index"[Start of Month]{[Index]+1} or [Label]<>#"Added Index"[Label]{[Index]+1}, type logical),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(ENDING, {{"Beginning", true},{"Ending",true}}),
    #"toKeep" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors", "toKeep", each [Beginning] or [Ending] , type logical),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(toKeep, each ([toKeep] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "toKeep"}),
    #"Added Index 2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index 2", "Stop", each if not[Ending] then #"Filtered Rows"[End of Month]{[Index]+1} else [End of Month]),
    #"Filtered Rows 2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom 1", each ([Ending] = false)),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows 2",{"Index", "Beginning", "Ending", "EOM_plus", "End of Month", "Label"}),
    #"Renamed Columns_1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns3",{{"Start of Month", "Start"}}),
    #"Renamed Columns_2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Renamed Columns_1",{{"Merged", "Label"}})


in
    #"Renamed Columns_2"
```

So, is there any more elegant way to obtain my target?

Comment: There probably is but your question needs detail. 1. You do not describe how the Skills in the Data Table are mapped to the Skills in the Result table and thence to the Label in the result table. 2. You have posted your data as a screenshot and not as text. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: My guess would be that the "Unpivot" is what's killing your performance.  Is possible to get your source data in the same format as after the "Unpivot"?

Answer (score 1):

Note: No one wants to retype your sample data. You need to provide that when asking a question

Below groups on Program and Skill and finds the first and last dates for those groups. The rest of your explanation is confusing

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Program", "Skill"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Program", "Skill"}, {
    {"Start", each List.First(Table.Sort(_,{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}})[Attribute])},
    {"Stop", each List.Last(Table.Sort(_,{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}})[Attribute])}
    })
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Program", "Skill"}, {{"data", each 
    let b=Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(_, {"Program", "Skill"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    c = Table.Sort(b,{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    d= #table({"Start","Stop"}, {{List.First(c[Attribute]),List.Last(c[Attribute])}})
in d, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Start", "Stop"}, {"Start", "Stop"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

| Program | Skill | 2023-07 | 2023-08 | 2023-09 | 2023-10 | 2023-11 | 2023-12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | S1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| P1 | S2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |  |  |
| P1 | S3 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  | 1 |
| P1 | S4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| P1 | S5 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| P2 | S1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| P2 | S3 |  |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| P3 | S3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| P3 | S4 |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| P4 | S2 | 1 |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want, but I don't know how fast it will be.

Caveats:

- I created a Label column but it doesn't match with the labels you show in your results.
- I did not translate your Skills from what you have in your data table to what you have in your results table.

If you can supply clear cut rules for the translations, it is probably doable, but might not be worthwhile.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],
     colTypes = List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source), {type text, type text} & List.Repeat({Int64.Type}, Table.ColumnCount(Source)-2)}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,colTypes),

//Group by Program and Skill
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Program", "Skill"}, {
        {"Start/Stop", (t)=>
            let 

        //Transpose to create two column table for each subgroup
                #"Demote & Transpose" = Table.Transpose(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveColumns(t,{"Program","Skill"}))),

        //Make dates out of Column1
                #"Make Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Demote & Transpose", {"Column1", each Date.From(_)}),

        //Add columns for each Program/Skill until we run out of people
                x = List.Accumulate(
                        {1..List.Max(#"Make Date"[Column2])-1},
                        #"Make Date", (state, current)=>
                        Table.AddColumn(state,"x" & Text.From(current), 
                            each if ([Column2]??0) > current then [Column2] - current else null)),

        //Stack the table into a single two column table
                colNames = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(x),2),
                #"2 Columns" = List.Accumulate(colNames,
                    Table.SelectColumns(x,{"Column1","Column2"}), (state, current)=>
                    Table.Combine({state,#table(null,{{null}}),
                        Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(x,{"Column1", current}),{current,"Column2"}) })),

        //Transform Column 2 into nulls or `1` for grouping
                #"Transform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"2 Columns", {"Column2", each if not (_ = null) then 1 else null}),

        //Get start and stop from each subgroups earliest and latest dates
        //  Changing the stop date to the end of the month
                #"Group" = Table.Group(#"Transform",{"Column2"}, {
                    {"Start", each List.Min([Column1]), type date},
                    {"Stop", each Date.EndOfMonth(List.Max([Column1])), type date}
                        }, GroupKind.Local),

        //Remove the null groups
                #"Remove Nulls" = Table.SelectRows(#"Group", each [Column2] <> null),

        //Add an Index column to be able to create labels
                #"Add Index" =Table.TransformColumns(Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Remove Nulls","Index",1,1),{"Index", each Text.From(_)})
            in 
                #"Add Index"}}),

    #"Expanded Start/Stop" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Start/Stop", {"Start", "Stop", "Index"}),
    #"Add Label Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Start/Stop", "Label", each Text.Combine({[Program],[Index]},"_"), type text),

//Cleanup
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Add Label Column",{"Program", "Skill", "Label", "Start", "Stop", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Index"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Start", type date}, {"Stop", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Data***

| Program | Skill | 2023-07 | 2023-08 | 2023-09 | 2023-10 | 2023-11 | 2023-12 | 2024-01 | 2024-02 | 2024-03 | 2024-04 | 2024-05 | 2024-06 | 2024-07 | 2024-08 | 2024-09 | 2024-10 | 2024-11 | 2024-12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Program_1 | Skill_1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Program_1 | Skill_2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Program_1 | Skill_3 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Program_1 | Skill_4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Program_1 | Skill_5 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Program_2 | Skill_1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Program_2 | Skill_3 |  |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Program_3 | Skill_3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Program_3 | Skill_4 |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Program_4 | Skill_2 | 1 |  | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are referencing the entire table `#"Added Index"` for each row in your table. So if you have 1,000 rows, you are re-loading the data from the `#"Added Index"` step 1,000 times. And I count at least 5 times you've used this approach.

Instead of referencing the table for each row, use `Table.Buffer`. This keeps a buffered copy of that step in memory, so you can refer to that buffered copy instead of reloading the data.

So instead of

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"EOM_plus", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"BEGINNING" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Beginning", each [Start of Month]<>#"Added Index"[EOM_plus]{[Index]-1} or [Label]<>#"Added Index"[Label]{[Index]-1}, type logical),
#"ENDING" = Table.AddColumn(#"BEGINNING", "Ending", each [EOM_plus]<>#"Added Index"[Start of Month]{[Index]+1} or [Label]<>#"Added Index"[Label]{[Index]+1}, type logical),
```

you can do

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"EOM_plus", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
Buffer = Table.Buffer(#"Added Index"),
#"BEGINNING" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Beginning", each [Start of Month]<>Buffer[EOM_plus]{[Index]-1} or [Label]<>Buffer[Label]{[Index]-1}, type logical),
#"ENDING" = Table.AddColumn(#"BEGINNING", "Ending", each [EOM_plus]<>Buffer[Start of Month]{[Index]+1} or [Label]<>Buffer[Label]{[Index]+1}, type logical),
```

and instead of

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(toKeep, each ([toKeep] = true)),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "toKeep"}),
#"Added Index 2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index 2", "Stop", each if not[Ending] then #"Filtered Rows"[End of Month]{[Index]+1} else [End of Month]),
```

you can do

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(toKeep, each ([toKeep] = true)),
#"Filtered Rows Buffer" = Table.Buffer(#"Filtered Rows"),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "toKeep"}),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Stop", each if not[Ending] then #"Filtered Rows Buffer"[End of Month]{[Index]+1} else [End of Month]),
```

This would probably speed things up, but @horseyride has given a better approach for your scenario that avoids the problem altogether.

Comment: I think that your answer hit the target. Now it is acceptable. I admit that I have to study better the Table.Buffer, because I can't understand why it is reloading as per your explanation the #"Added Index" while is not by pointing to a table buffer.